# When border right and left color goes transparent, line appears in FF

Tags: html, css

i created one half circle in css using border styles. To make circle, i gave border right and left colors transparent and it works fine in chrome but some line is coming inside circle in Firefox only. Anyone any idea about this ?

here the link
[codepen.io/imarun/pen/ggOdoN](https://codepen.io/imarun/pen/ggOdoN)

```css
body {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-size: 64px;
}

.outer {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  margin-left: -50px;
  margin-top: -50px;
}
.outer p {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  line-height: 100px;
  background: antiquewhite;
  border-radius: 10%;
}
.outer p:hover .round:before {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(225deg) scale(0.5) translate(-10px, -10px);
          transform: rotate(225deg) scale(0.5) translate(-10px, -10px);
  box-shadow: inset 1px 1px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
}
.outer p:hover .round:after {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
          transform: rotate(0deg);
}
.outer p:hover .dots:before,
.outer p:hover .dots:after {
  -webkit-transform: scaleY(1);
          transform: scaleY(1);
}

.round {
  position: absolute;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  left: 80px;
  top: 24px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-right-color: transparent;
  z-index: 100;
}
.round:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  display: block;
  border: 25px solid grey;
  border-right-color: transparent;
  border-bottom-color: transparent;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg) scale(1) translate(0, 0);
          transform: rotate(45deg) scale(1) translate(0, 0);
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.5s ease-in;
  transition: -webkit-transform 0.5s ease-in;
  transition: transform 0.5s ease-in;
  transition: transform 0.5s ease-in, -webkit-transform 0.5s ease-in;
  top: 0;
  border-radius: 50%;
  z-index: 90;
}
.round:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  top: -1px;
  left: -1px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  border-right-color: black;
  z-index: 99;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.5s ease-in;
  transition: -webkit-transform 0.5s ease-in;
  transition: transform 0.5s ease-in;
  transition: transform 0.5s ease-in, -webkit-transform 0.5s ease-in;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
          transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
.round .dots {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.round .dots:before,
.round .dots:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  top: 35%;
  left: 25%;
  width: 5px;
  height: 5px;
  background: black;
  border-radius: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: scaleY(0);
          transform: scaleY(0);
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.3s 0.7s ease;
  transition: -webkit-transform 0.3s 0.7s ease;
  transition: transform 0.3s 0.7s ease;
  transition: transform 0.3s 0.7s ease, -webkit-transform 0.3s 0.7s ease;
}
.round .dots:after {
  right: 25%;
  left: auto;
}
.round.round1 {
  left: 140px;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto" rel="stylesheet">

  <style>
  </style>

</head>
<div class="outer">
  <p>FR
    <span class="round">
      <span class="dots"></span>
    </span>

    <span class="round round1">
      <span class="dots"></span>
    </span>
  </p>
</div>

<!-- <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
  width="285.333px" height="286.667px" viewBox="0 0 285.333 286.667" enable-background="new 0 0 285.333 286.667"
  xml:space="preserve">

  <style>
    svg *{
   -moz-transition:all 0.3s ease-out;
   -o-transition:all 0.3s ease-out;
   -webkit-transition:all 0.3s ease-out;
    transition:all 0.3s ease-out;
     }

    svg:hover .cutpart{
     transform: translate(62px);
    }
  </style>

<g>
 <path fill="none" stroke="#3FA9F5" stroke-width="5" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M281.258,142.812
  c0-76.62-62.113-138.732-138.732-138.732S3.793,66.192,3.793,142.812s62.113,138.732,138.732,138.732
  c31.112,0,59.832-10.241,82.972-27.536"/>
 <path class="cutpart" fill="none" stroke="#3FA9F5" stroke-width="5" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M225.498,254.008
  c24.46-18.281,42.687-44.444,50.916-74.724c3.158-11.622,4.844-23.85,4.844-36.472"/>
 <circle fill="#FFFFFF" stroke="#3FA9F5" stroke-width="5" stroke-miterlimit="10" cx="89.147" cy="94.967" r="10.058"/>
 <circle fill="#FFFFFF" stroke="#3FA9F5" stroke-width="5" stroke-miterlimit="10" cx="197.147" cy="94.967" r="10.058"/>
 <path fill="#2375AD" stroke="#3FA9F5" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M68.765,164.833c0,41,33.024,73.761,73.761,73.761
  c40.737,0,73.761-32.761,73.761-73.761H68.765z"/>
 <path fill="#144F70" d="M81.765,170.833c0,33,27.203,60.761,60.761,60.761c33.557,0,60.761-27.761,60.761-60.761H81.765z"/>
</g>
</svg> -->
```

Comment: Let me know if my answer worked and can be accepted, or else I delete it.

Comment: It didnt work @LGSon

Comment: @LGSon Please put your answer , i didnt test with transfrom rotate and eyes inside ... so put ur answer ... :)

Comment: Please review and comment on my updated answer, and let me know if something is unclear or missing. It would also be great if you could accept and/or upvote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you simplify the way you create those "e" signs, you won't get those issues

*A side note: The issue you have in the original code is in the way you set the `border` on the `.round`'s pseudo rule `&:before`. If you for example give it a red background, those white lines becomes red, so I guess this is an anti-aliasing issue.*

*I solved that by using the background color instead, in combination with rounding the upper left and right border*

```css
.outer p {
  font-size: 64px;
  margin: 0;
}
.outer p > span {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  top: 2px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}
.outer p > span + span {
  margin-left: 7px;
}
.outer p > span::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0; top: 0;
  height: 50%;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-width: 1px 1px 0 1px;
  background: gray;
  border-top-left-radius: 50px;
  border-top-right-radius: 50px;  
  transition: transform 0.5s;
  transform-origin: center bottom;
}
.outer p > span::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0; top: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-right-color: transparent;
  border-radius: 50%;
  transform: rotate(10deg);
  transition: border-color 0.5s;
}

.outer p > span span {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.outer p > span span::before,
.outer p > span span::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 15px; top: 15px;
  width: 5px;
  height: 5px;
  background: gray;
  border-radius: 50%;
  transform: scaleY(0);
  transition: transform 0.2s 0.3s;
}
.outer p > span span::after {
  left: 30px;
}

.outer p:hover > span::before {
  border-right-color: black;
}
.outer p:hover > span::after {
  color: black;
  transform: translateY(10%) scale(0.6) rotate(180deg);
}
.outer p:hover > span span::before,
.outer p:hover > span span::after {
  transform: scaleY(1);
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <p>FR<span><span></span></span><span><span></span></span>
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for answer @LGSon but can u tell me how that white lines coming and from where ?